# Downloading a user's file through PHP to Android device

Tags: php, android, download, server

The task I'm trying to do is download a specific user's file, called "UserNo123.db" for example(Not a pure text file), it's in a private directory.

The android app should pass the name of the file needed based on the user using the app, and then download that file and save it somewhere in the device's storage.

User's ID ->Android App sends ID to PHP script -> PHP Script uses ID to get file -> sends it back to app -> app receives correct file and saves it in a local directory

I know little about php, so I apologize if I got something basic wrong.

```
    String path ="http://LOCALHOST/testdownload.php";
                        URL u = null;
                        try {
                            u = new URL(path);
                            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                            c.connect();
                            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                            final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
                            bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Log.d("READING",bo.toString());
                                    try {
                                        bo.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

PHP file:

```
    <?php

    $attachment_location = "databases/test.txt";
            if (file_exists($attachment_location)) {

                header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
                header("Cache-Control: public"); // needed for i.e.
                header("Content-Type: application/txt");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
                header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($attachment_location) . "\"");   
                header("Content-Length:".filesize($attachment_location));
                readfile($attachment_location);
                die();        
            } else {
                die("Error: File not found.");
            } 

    ?>
```

This is what I got to download a file, although for some reason while trying to read a text file as an example, it gives me extra characters, but at least there wasn't an error for now.

Now, from what I know, I would want to have my request method be "POST" so I can send the needed query (User's id), how can I do that while still getting the file?

Thank you

Comment: You do not need to POST to send the Id. GET can do that too. `String path ="http://LOCALHOST/testdownload.php?id=abc123";` or `String path ="http://LOCALHOST/testdownload.php?filename=abc123.txt"` Remove the die() from the php script. Only use die() when things go wrong.

Comment: `it gives me extra characters`. Please elaborate.

Comment: `app receives correct file and saves it in a local directory`. Then do not use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` in between. Better use a `FileOutputStream` directly.

Comment: Thank you! I used GET, I don't know how I forgot about that...
As for extra characters, it's probably from a wrong content-type, it's working fine now, it used to give me "Textfile contents"+loads of symbols

I used FileOutputStream, file downloads correctly, thank you yet again! It seems to be working very well so far!

Comment: Although one weird thing happened, I made a BufferedReader read the input stream to get if there was any error(File not found etc), but when I do that, the database file downloaded is corrupt, and when I comment out that checking portion with the BufferedReader, the download works well and is not corrupt.
I fixed that by making a separate php file to check if the file exists or not without opening it, then a separate PHP file to get the file, each of them with a different InputStream, and it worked.

Comment: Wow. I've been writing code the wrong way all along! I've never  EVER thought of using get! Perhaps put your comment as an answer? It's extremely helpful!